# Macro for merging cells in multiple columns across the same row

Tags: excel, merge, vba

I am creating a kind of database if you will and i have multiple columns in the one row that need to be merged and am wondering if it's possible to do this with a macro.

To make it even more difficult the amount of cells to merge isn't constant. 
IE:

```
  1 A   B   C   MARY JO         50  main office     admin

  2 A   B   C   MARY JO         50  main office     admin

  3 A   B   C   MARY JO         50  main office     admin

  1 A   B   C   JOHN DOE        60  OTHER office    driver

  2 A   B   C   JOHN DOE        60  OTHER office    driver
```

Merge rows 1-3 and 4-5 is the desired outcome. Hard to explain without ability to post picture but column A and Z onwards want UNMERGED as each individual row has information displayed in these columns.

WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE NOW:
[image]

DESIRED FINAL OUTCOME:
[image]

Comment: Are the only items that differ in the first two columns? If that is the case then is the data in the first two columbns relevant?

Comment: How many rows are there?

Comment: Data in Column A differs and needs to remain unmerged. data in columns B-H to be merged with identical column in rows beneath.

Comment: there are about 700 rows of data. Columns out to CS

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub MergeTheseCellsToMakeSomethingLikeADatabase()
    'Crucial Line Below
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim i%
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
       For i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count to 2 Step -1
          If .Cells(i,4).Value = .Cells(i-1,4).Value Then
             .Range(.Cells(i,2),.Cells(i-1,2)).Merge
             .Range(.Cells(i,3),.Cells(i-1,3)).Merge
             .... 
             'Do this for all rows that are relevant or just have another for loop to cycle
             'Through the rows that you want merged      
          End If
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this with formulae on another worksheet to create the desired outcome - macros are likely not needed unless you are trying to automate the entire process.  If this is just a one-off then macros are definitely overkill.

Create coluumns with the desired combination of cells simply by creatign aformula like:

=A1&A3  etc

& is used instead of + to join text cells together (concatenate)

Copy that formuala down for each column and done... almost...

Now you can worry about merging rows

Wing

Comment: i don't think i have explained it well. That isn't the desired outcome

Comment: Of course my apologies for not being clear was having problems with pictures post now edited with links to image should make much clearer

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove duplicate rows? If so highlight your data range and then from the menu select Data. On the Data ribbon go to the Sort and Filter section and click on advanced. In the advanced filter dialog select 'Copy to another location', make sure the List range has selected you data, in the copy to box select where you want your filtered list to go and then tick the box for unique records only. Click OK and job done.

Comment: Thank you for the help but i am not trying to delete duplicate rows. I am doing a resource chart so breaking a persons time into hours for different tasks. Hence the data that remains constant (ie name/location/rate) would like to merge but other rows need to stay divided as they represent different tasks.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a Pivot table.

Comment: Hmmm.....Maybe! It's a the data for a Histogram but want to present it  in table form as well as a graph. very large complicated amounts of information but maybe with a bit of work to make it all flat data a pivot table COULD work I will experiment.

Comment: You could do a Pivot table and a Pivot graph both using the same data set.

Comment: due to nature of the data pivot table just doesn't sort it how i need it would be much easier to just merge those cells