# Macro for merging rows in multiple columns across the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I have several thousand rows of data in this Excel sheet. I'm trying to come up with a macro to merge same number of rows in the second column across all the columns. But there are some values in other columns which aren't the same, so will only merge the rows that are the same values.

**EDIT:** This question is not a duplicate. It differs from the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18587332/4573998), the fourth columns cant merge all rows with the same values as it can ONLY merge the rows in the fourth columns if the sequential rows in the second column are of the same values. This is because all the values in the fourth columns are 95% the same.

Original Sheet:
[image]

Desired Merging:
[image]

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587332/macro-for-merging-cells-in-multiple-columns-across-the-same-row wasn't of any use?

Comment: Thanks @TylerH. I solved it with your suggestion. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [TylerH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh)  for the code suggestion. Here is the adjusted code for future references:

```
Private Sub MergeTheseCellsToMakeSomethingLikeADatabase()

'Crucial Line Below

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i%
Dim j%
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY")
   For j = 6 To 2 Step -1
        For i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 2).Value And .Cells(i, j).Value = .Cells(i - 1, j).Value Then
            .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i - 1, j)).Merge


            'Do this for all rows that are relevant or just have another for loop to cycle
            'Through the rows that you want merged

            End If
        Next
   Next
End With
End Sub
```